# Create Webservice's datacontract dynamically

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a webservice which needs to return data.

```
[DataMember]
public Int32 RequestId
{
    get { return requestId; }
    set { requestId = value; }
}

[DataMember]
public string StatusCode
{
    get { return statusCode; }
    set { statusCode = value; }
}

[DataMember]
public List<string> ErrorMessages
{
    get { return errorMessages; }
    set { errorMessages = value; }
}

[DataMember]
public string PeriodStatus
{
    get { return status; }
    set { status = value; }
}
[DataMember]
public string PhoneNumber
{
    get { return status; }
    set { status = value; }
}
```

Now some users of the service want to receive the phonenumber, others don't want to receive that field.

These preferences are stored in a database.

Is there a way to make the response dynamically based on whether they have chosen to receive the field or not?

Comment: according to  your questions tags , Do you use asp.net soap web service ?

Comment: @Z.R.T. yes I do, sorry

Comment: Asp.Net Soap Web Service project or WCF  ?

Comment: Soap Web Service project

Comment: SOAP Web Service doesn't use contract...May i know, how you gonna specify when return data with phone number when without ?

Comment: Well that's my problem, I was wondering if this is possible. I have a table in the database which contains flags for each field which can be returned. if the flag is True, the customer wants to receive the data. At this moment they receive an XML-file, but they want to start using a SOAP-service (or other service)

Comment: can you create two datacontracts , one with Phone Number, another without ?

Comment: i could do that, but there are many more fields that can be returned in a lot of different combinations. if it were only the phonenumber, I would just create two contracts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't change returning data from service in runtime, because client has a batch of files including wsdl as description of web service. Evenmore , when web service has been modified , client need to update web references.

In your case, when you don't know number of fields must be returning from service , you can return the collection of fields.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[XmlInclude(typeof(CustomFieldCollection))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(CustomField))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(CustomField[]))]
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public Service()
    {
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public CustomFieldCollection GetFieldsCollection()
    {
        CustomFieldCollection collection = new CustomFieldCollection();
        collection["fieldA"] = 1;
        collection["fieldB"] = true;
        collection["fieldC"] = DateTime.Now;
        collection["fieldD"] = "hello";
        CustomFieldCollection collection1 = new CustomFieldCollection();
        collection1["fieldA"] = 1;
        collection1["fieldB"] = true;
        collection1["fieldC"] = DateTime.Now;
        collection1["fieldD"] = "hello";
        collection.Collection[0].CustomFields = collection1;
        return collection;
    }
}
public class CustomFieldCollection
{
    private List<CustomField> fields = new List<CustomField>();

    public object this[String name]
    {
        get { return fields.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name); }
        set
        {
            if (!fields.Exists(x => x.Name == name))
            {
                fields.Add(new CustomField(name, value));
            }
            else
            {
                this[name] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public CustomField[] Collection
    {
        get { return fields.ToArray(); }
        set { }
    }
}


public class CustomField
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public CustomFieldCollection CustomFields { get; set; }

    public CustomField()
    {
    }

    public CustomField(string name, object value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

You can modify GetFieldsCollection method, return collection of fields for specific type passed as parameter.

Comment: Would it be possible to have a CustomFieldCollection which contains another CustomFieldCollection ?

Comment: yes, it possible , just add    `public CustomFieldCollection CustomFields { get; set; }`  in CustomField class. @BartSchelkens check answer update